# why laravel passport always parses user_id of oauth_access_tokens to integer?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm new to the laravel passport, I used it to authenticate my api service.
My 'user' table has column 'phone' varchar(255) as a primary key.
When I pass it to get an access token, Laravel always parses it to an integer number, so the phone number 01233456789 will become 1233456789 without zero before it. 
I have tried to change the data type of 'oauth_access_tokens.user_id' column to varchar(255), but it still not works.
So, how to fix it.

here are some images:

image 1
[image: oauth_access_tokens.user_id]

image 2
[image: request param]

Comment: inlining the images

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have done it by adding

```
protected $casts = ['phone' => 'string'];
```

in my User model.